# What is the naming rule behind Rails' parts?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Some Rails' parts start with "Active":

- ActiveRecord
- ActiveModel
- ActiveSupport

And some Rails' parts start with "Action":

- ActionPack
- ActionView
- ActionMailer

Why is that? Why don't they all have the same prefix? And what do "Active" and "Action" mean in this context?

DHH is now building "ActiveJob", and how did he know if it wasn't supposed to be "ActionJob"?

Comment: ActiveRecord was named after the Active Record pattern (Martin Fowler PEAA),
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Active_record_pattern

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The way I look at it, again this is just my perspective (*the only person who can give a confirmed answer is DHH :)* ),

When I see `Action*` like `ActionPack` (`ActionView` and `ActionController` are the two major components of `ActionPack`) or `ActionMailer`, they pertain to an **action** performed within the Rails application be it a controller specific action or displaying a particular view  or even sending an email. So, `Action` seems precise prefix here as these packages denote doing something.

When I see `Active*` like `ActiveRecord`, `ActiveSupport` or `ActiveModel` etc., it somehow relates to providing some useful functionality to your Rails applications business logic be it utility methods or ORM support kind of like add-ons to facilitate the Rails application development.

Hope to see more interesting answers on this question. This is where we can start analyzing.

Comment: This is a really good answer. Yeah, for example, both ActionPack and ActionMailer work in "actions", and they're not usable in e.g. Rake tasks, but Active* parts are.

Comment: @janko-m I don't know, which book, you are reading for Rails. But if you really wanted to understand, take a tour first 2 chaps of *part-3* of this [book](http://pragprog.com/book/rails4/agile-web-development-with-rails-4). I can grantee you don't need to look back. It explains all. What you wanted to know, is present in the book. This answer didn't explain this and it is out of scope.

Comment: @ArupRakshit the book doesn't say anything about why Active* / Action* prefix. Thats what OP wants to know. The book or official Rails guide explains what is ActiveRecord or ActionPack... which is basic foundation of Rails framework. I agree with Kirti's perspective.

Comment: @user3317140 Thanks for the reply. I don't agree also. The question was hitting the design *moto*. That has not been explained here too and it is out of scope. This answer explain which expands to what.But readers have their own perspective, you might thought it answered, I don't think 100% not answered. Besides also I would say, it is out of scope too. *the book doesn't say anything about why Active* / Action* prefix* - Really ? That book is a *black book* for me. And it explains all, which it missed, there is another one, they did explain those.

Comment: @ArupRakshit I disagree. I don't think book says anything abt prefix terminolgy at all. Why dont u post an aswer that u think book explains

Comment: @user3317140 Because it will take pages, and that wouldn't fit in SO. I thought, then I decided not to do, better to mention the resource.

Comment: @user3317140 I was looking for a good answer to gave you and to make you feel, what in SO really making me annoyed. Thank God I got a [blog](http://michael.richter.name/blogs/why-i-no-longer-contribute-to-stackoverflow) written by well known person.First 3 comments, you can take as my answers, the same effect you can encounter if you look into my *activity graph*. Question is quality is degrading day-by-day, in SO, by people who asks questions and contributors too.If you consider this question and you go to the *close for voting* option,

Answer (score 3):

Action* is for user facing stuff (views, controllers, mailers) and Active* are backend components that supports the Action* components

Answer (score 0):

ActiveRecord is based on a software pattern coined by Martin Fowler called "Active Record" ([wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Active_record_pattern)).

I know that does not exactly explain a naming convention, but it does explain where the name came from.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like:

**Action**: providing functionality for the **Controller**.

**Active** providing functionality for the **Model**.

However, I'm not so sure.