# Rails active vs action (Railties naming)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, naming

Railties in Rails are named starting either with **active** or **action**:

- *action* mailer
- *action* pack
- *action* view
- *active* job
- *active* model
- *active* record
- *active* support

What's the difference between **active** and **action**, and what do these words have to do with component's contents or functionality?

Comment: check if you like this -- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23747162/what-is-the-naming-rule-behind-rails-parts/23747647#23747647

Comment: @ArupRakshit, oh thanks, didn't manage to find this.

Answer (score 2):

Action names represents the **controller** layer (and the **view** layer), responsible for handling incoming HTTP requests and providing a suitable response.

Active names represents the **model** layer. Represents your domain model and encapsulates the business logic that is specific to your application.

This text is from the README.md file in the Rails repository:
https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/README.md

Comment: well, `active support` doesn't really belong to model layer I think.

Comment: Active Support is perhaps the exception. Maybe in its starts they created it as a collection of helpers for the models, dunno. But definitely, active support doesn't match as an Active one.

Comment: @FranMartinez there is something called `ActionCable` (coming soon!) too.. :) No idea, based on really what conventions they do select those names.

Comment: I didn't know about ActionCable. But I think the name has sense: ActionCable is about websockets and connections, so it's about requests. Look at the readme file: https://github.com/rails/actioncable